# Alamofire returning html code instead of json

Tags: swift, alamofire

So I am trying to use alamofire to pull from my firebase database as opposed to the library functions.

```
@objc func fetchData(){
    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.sneakerAPI).responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result


        switch response.result {
        case .success(let val):
            print(val)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }

}
```

I have written this small method that should efficitevly pull the data however I just get a whole bunch of html code that looks nothing like whats in the database.

I have also temporarily made rules public for read and write

https://sneakerapi.firebaseio.com/

So i don't see what is wrong with this function.

Comment: Are you sure the API is actually returning JSON for your request? When this happened to me in the past, it turned out that it was actually returning a PHP error page instead. Try loading the URL in the browser and see what it shows you.

Comment: its weird when i type in the url it takes me right to the dashboard or prompts me to sign in @JohnMontgomery

Comment: I may have figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. All I had to was add .json at the end of the aformentioned url